# Code does not save .csv file properly

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a excel workbook that i want to save as a csv file. 
This is the code i use:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
"C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\1. QUOTES\3. PROGRAM FILES\DOOR QT REQUESTS\DOORS_COMBINED.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
, CreateBackup:=False


Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\1. QUOTES\3. PROGRAM FILES\DOOR QT REQUESTS\DOOR PROGRAM.xlsm")

Workbooks("DOORS_COMBINED.csv").Close
```

The problem is when i save it it does not look the same as the excel workbook.

Excel file:

```
  A        B      C       D
Item 1  Item 2  Item3   Item 4
Item 1  Item 2  Item3   Item 4
Item 1  Item 2  Item3   Item 4
```

.CSV File: (Everything gets combined into column A)

```
          A                    B        C       D
Item 1Item 2Item3Item 4
Item 1Item 2Item3Item 4
Item 1Item 2Item3Item 4
```

If i save this manually as a .csv it turns out correct.

I think this could be the problem. I set excel to read the delimeter as ; because my descriptions contain commas.

[image: File opened in notebook]

[image]

Notepad view when using VBA to SaveAs:

Notepad view when SaveAs manually:

Comment: Does Excel file actually contain commas between columns as you show? Also , you are saving the `ActiveWorkbook` as csv, then continue on with additional programming. Lines after are done in a csv file. When you exit, macros are lost. You might have conflict. Try saving to csv and exiting right after. Also might consider saving `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Your code shows you saving `DOORS_COMBINED.csv` and then opening `DOOR PROGRAM.xlsm`. So when you're opening the file you're unhappy with, are you opening it manually? Does it prompt you to specify how the file is delimited by chance?

Comment: The excel file doesn't actually contain commas. I tried running the code i have by commenting out the open and leaving the close workbook in and it still does whats above. I tried commenting both the open and close, and this made me close the new saved as file manually. This prompts me if i wanna save and everything and it then saves the file correctly. This is what I'm trying to get around. I want the user to just click the button and have it save correctly

Comment: @Marc I reopen PROGRAM.xlsm because my macros are in there and i need to run a few more operations after i save as. I tried a few things and was having conflicts with files being opened and closed. Was easier just to seperate the save as .csv. Maybe wont ave to do that after i figure this out. Yes I'm opening it the output file manually because I'm checking to see if it save right. I have another button that does stuff to it after this. When saving it does not ask what delimiter to use. Let me know if i can clarify anything else.

Comment: Excel does not recognize the delimiter?

Comment: @Jelly Then whats the difference when i click save as .csv and run vba code to save it as .csv? It must recognize it cause when i do it manually the output file is correct. Is there a way to check what its trying to read as the delimiter? When i record the steps it gives me the same code as i posted. Thanks

Comment: What do you see if you open `DOORS_COMBINED.csv` with notepad (try it on a small example)?

Comment: Might be a *locale* problem. Try adding to `SaveAs` the parameter `local:=True`

Comment: @A.S.H Opened the file in notepad and noticed the delimeter was commas. I'm guessing this is the default for excel. I know i change it in my control panel to read delimeters as semi-colons because my descriptions contain commas. I dunno if this helps to solve the problem but i think this could be whats wrong.

Comment: Did you try `SaveAs ...  local:=True` ? also, please check with notepad what you get when you save as CSV manually, since you said it works fine when you save manually.

Comment: I did try SaveAs ....Local: True but it didn't change the outcome. Uploaded the notepad view of what happens when saved manually above. As i thought it has the semi-colon as the delimiter. @A.S.H

Comment: What exact steps do you do when you "save it manually"? What "Save as type" do you select?

Comment: File, Save As, CSV (MS Dos), Save @coders!

Comment: Well I think you are in a real particular case. you changed the delimiter for Excel for reading CSV to be `;`, but you did not set it as the delimiter in the regional settings. Unfortunately, the only way to control the delimiter in VBA `SaveAs` in through the `local` parameter. You need to set the semi-colon as list separator in the system's `Regional Settings, and then use `local:=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution has been alluded to multiple times but to be clear.

This works for me:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\test_out.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
```

The trick is the `local:=True` and making sure that your regional settings `List separator` is a semicolon.

To set the `List separator`, open `Control Panel => Region and Language`, click on `Additional settings` and change `List separator:` to `;`

Comment: Thanks @codersl I dunno what i did before but i must have been in a hurry. Thanks for all the help! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this format

```
FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS
```

and try to add after *CreateBackup:=False* this line

```
, Local:=True
```

Comment: Just tried this and it doesnt work. It saves it as a blank .csv file. I had my finger crossed =) @Oskar Shon Thanks